# Assign a Parent item with Child data in nested repeater C#

Tags: c#, code-behind, nested-repeater

Can you set a parent tag (Label) with a child data within a nested repeater?

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rpDB" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpDB_ItemDataBound" EnableViewState="true">
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <label class="glyphicon glyphicon-leaf" /><label id="rbt" runat="server"></label>
                  <asp:Repeater ID="rpDB_item" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpDB_item_ItemDataBound">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <div class="row anj">
                                                <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-1 glyphicon glyphicon-off" id="lblboot" runat="server" title=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"boot") %>></div> 
                                              </div>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:Repeater>    
                 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I would like to set label `rbt` in the parent repeater `rpDB` with the value of the `lblboot` in the child repeater `rpDB_Item`.  Is this possible, and if so how.  I see plenty pulling parent into child but not reversed.

Comment: Still no luck finding anything.  Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.  I thought I had used this but must have been doing it wrong.
`(HtmlGenericControl) mycontrol = (HtmlGenericControl)(e.Item.Parent.Parent.FindControl("myControl"));`

This allowed me to set the attributes to a parent control.

Comment: What I don't understand is why would I have to use `....Parent.Parent...` instead of just a single Parent?